# How to extract commas and decimal places from text in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a document I would like to import to excel which contains something like this (GHC33.45). How can I extract only the numbers and decimal places into another cell.
(There are instances where there is; Ghc234.00, Ghc2,300.00) I want to be able to keep both commas and decimal places.

I have seen answers for a question like this however, the answers are always tailored to the question being asked.

Comment: Of course the other answers are tailored, just like this one would be. The trick is to adapt those other solutions to yours; the solutions get you started down the right path, and you use them as a base to form your own tailored solution. Start off by trying to do that, and then if you run into difficulties you can post your efforts so far and ask a specific question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you always have three characters at the front that you wish to discard, then with data in **A1**, in another cell enter:

```
=MID(A1,4,9999)
```

[image]

If your data has a variable number of junk characters before and after the number, then you could use the following User Defined Function:

```
Public Function eXtractor(rin As Range) As String
    Dim v As String, L As String, i As Long, CH As String
    eXtractor = ""
    v = rin.Text
    L = Len(v)

    For i = 1 To L
        CH = Mid(v, i, 1)
        If CH Like "[0-9]" Or CH = "," Or CH = "." Then
            eXtractor = eXtractor & CH
        End If
    Next i
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You would do this in two steps:

1. First load the data as it is into one column
2. Add a column in which you put the formula to extract the numerical data from the first column

Assuming your data is loaded in column A, put the formula in column B. In B1 you would put this:

```
=NUMBERVALUE(MID(A1;4;10000), ".", ",")
```

This first takes all the text from A1, except for the first 3 characters, and then it converts that to a number, specifying what the decimal point (`.`) and thousands separator (`,`) is in the column A values.

Drag this formula down the whole B column until the row where the data in column A ends.

Then format that column as numerical format with 2 decimals (or whatever you want to have displayed).

This way you can do calculations with the values in column B, like making a total with `=SUM(B1:B999)`

Comment: Thanks for your answer...very greatfull. But I get errors when tried to use this method.

Comment: Corrected. I had localised separators (I am in Europe) and used 2013 function which might not be available for you. Should be OK now.